# SQL Azure performance considerations

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design, azure-sql-database, database-performance

Which are the performance considerations I should keep in mind when I'm planning an SQL Azure application? Azure Storage, and the worker and the web roles looks very scalable, but if at the end they are using one database... it looks like the bottleneck.

I was trying to find numbers about:

1. How many concurrent connections does
   SQL Azure support?
2. Which is the bandwidth?

But no luck.

For example, I'm planning and application that uses a very high level of inserts, but I need return the result of an aggregate function each time (e.g.: the sum of all records with same key in a column), so I can not go with table storage.

Batching is an option, but time response is critical as well, so I'm afraid the database will be bloated with lot of connections.

Sharding is another option, but even when the amount of inserts is massive, the amount of data is very small, 4 to 6 columns with one PK and no FK. So even a 1Gb DB would be an overkill (and an overpay :D) for a partition.

Which would be the performance keys I should keep in mind when I'm facing these kind of applications?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Achieving both scalability and performance can be very difficult, even in the cloud. Your question was primarily about scalability, so you may want to design your application in such a way that your data becomes "eventually" consistent, using queues for example. A worker role would listen for incoming insert requests and would perform the insert asynchronously.

To minimize the number of roundtrips to the database and optimize connection pooling make sure to batch your inserts as well. So you could send 100 inserts in one shot. Also keep in mind that SQL Azure now supports MARS (multiple active recordsets) so that you can return multiple SELECTs in a single batch back to the calling code. The use of batching and MARS should reduce the number of database connections to a minimum.

Sharding usually helps for Read operations; not so much for inserts (although I never benchmarked inserts with sharding). So I am not sure sharding will help you that much for your requirements.

Remember that the Azure offering is designed first for scalability and reasonable performance in a multitenancy environment, where your database is shared with others on the same server. So if you need strong performance with guaranteed response time you may need to reevaluate your hosting choices or indeed test the performance boundaries of Azure for your needs as suggested by tijmenvdk.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Azure will throttle your connections if any form of resource contention occurs (this includes heavy load but might also occur when your database is physically moved around). Throttling is non-deterministic, meaning that you cannot predict if and when this happens. When throttling, SQL Azure will drop your connection, requiring you to perform a retry. Number of connections supported and bandwidth is not published "by design" due to the flexible nature of the underlying infrastructure. Having said that, the setup is optimized for high availability, not high throughput.

If the bursts happen at a known time, you might consider sharding just during those bursts and consolidating the data after the burst has happened. Another way to handle this, is to start queueing/batching writes if and only if throttling occurs. You can use an Azure Queue for that plus a worker role to empty the queue later. This "overflow mechanism" has the advantage of automatically engaging if throttling occurs.

As an alternative you could use Azure Table Storage and keep a separate table of running totals that you can report back instead of performing an aggregation over the data to return the required sum of all records (this might be tricky due to the lack of locking on the tables though).

Apologies for stating the obvious, but the first step would be to test if you run into throttling at all in your scenario. I would give the overflow solution a try.